# Does CPU speed matter if the RAM is low?

Tags: memory, cpu

I was just comparing my laptop with school computers with my friend. But we hit a problem, since school computers have 2GB of ram, they are worser than mine, but they have 2x 3.20GHz CPUs. Now, does good cpu really matter if having low ram?

Bonus question lol: If I have lower-clocked i3, is it still better than Core 2 (2x 3.20GHz)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUs have had several generational improvements over the years, resulting in significant improvements in clock-for-clock performance and power savings.

The net result is that a current generation i3 could potentially outperform an older generation and higher clocked device.

Having a lower amount of RAM could exacerbate the situation and cause the machine to "stall" while paging memory to or from the page file. Having a higher clocked processor will not really help if the CPU is left waiting for program data from the hard disk.